# Prevent Window Boundary from Over Screen Boundary when SizeChange

Tags: c#, wpf

How to prevent Window Boundary from over Screen Boundary when Window SizeChange in C# WPF?

(that's Restrict Window Boundary in Screen )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Window's OnSizeChanged Event,

and do like this:

```
 //get Screen's Width, Height
 private double screenHeight = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight;
 private double screenWidth = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth;
 private void MultiToolWindow_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     //when window RightBoundary over screen
     if (this.Left + this.Width > screenWidth)  
         this.Width = screenWidth-this.Left;  //shrink the width
     //when window DownBoundary over screen
     if (this.Top + this.Height > screenHeight)
         this.Height = screenHeight-this.Top; //shrink the height
 }
```

Note that when using this, Window's SizeToContent Property should be in Manual,

if not,

you can change it like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(){

    //set to manual, this will invoke OnSizeChangedEvent at the same time but the shrink code won't work
    this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;

    //this will invoke OnSizeChangedEvent and because now is manual the shrink code works
    this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;


}
```

do twice to ensure when window's original SizeToContent State is WidthAndHeight can take effect too,

first time will set it to Manual and the shrink code won't take effect,

and second time cause the state is manual so the shrink code will take effect.